# Marcar color a un txtbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]He intentando con esta opción realizar un cambio de color a un campo de texto pero no me ha funcionado.

```
txtListaProcesos.BackColor = Color.Red
```

Algún otro método que pueda usar

Comment: A ver..esa linea tiene que cambiar el color de fondo, asi que alguna informacion nos falta. Estamos hablando de winforms? wpf? asp.net? Por otro lado, en que momento llamas a ese codigo? en el constructor del formulario? en algun evento? Te da algun error al compilar? Te lanza una excepción? O simplemente no cambia el color? Pulsa [edit] y añade mas informacion.

Comment: Ese es el mensaje que tengo de error. La unica opción en el programa para poner color es ColorPalettes

Comment: O sea..estamos hablando de asp.net? Si es asi, prueba con `txtListaProcesos.BackColor = = System.Drawing.Color.Red`

Comment: Esta programado en c# el codigo mostrado  y asp.net la parte del txtbox

Comment: Prueba lo que te he puesto en mi anterior comentario.

Comment: Sigue sin reconocerme la parte de System.Drawing.Red

Comment: si perdona, es `System.Drawing.Color.Red`. Mira la respuesta de @RogerTorné si no para entenderlo mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora si

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que te falta la referencia a `System.Drawing` que es donde reside la clase `Color`

O bien haces una referencia directa:

```
txtListaProcesos.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

O la referencias en tu clase:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

y dejas el código como lo tenías:

```
txtListaProcesos.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: gracias ahora si.

Answer (score 0):

Tu linea `txtListaProcesos.BackColor = Color.Red`  cambia el color del fondo de tu control a color Rojo.

Esta linea `txtListaProcesos.ForeColor = Color.Blue;` cambia el color de la fuente, es decir del texto a color azul.

Comment: Creo que te has liado, es justo al revés: `ForeColor` cambia el color de la fuente y `BackColor` el del fondo.

Comment: @RogerTorné Tienes razón, copié y pegué texto y no revisé adecuadamente, lo edito para evitar que otros se vayan con el error.

Comment: Hola, si la he cambiado y no me sirve tampoco. Al parecer en mi biblioteca de c# no tiene esa función para llamar a los colores.